# Failure to initialize configurationInvalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks

I am attempting to use cloudfiles AutoLoader in databricks, accessing a storage account through SAS token. It has yet to work, and I always hit the same error noting:

```
Failure to initialize configurationInvalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key
```

Code:

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "SAS")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.token.provider.type.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.sas.FixedSASTokenProvider")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.fixed.token.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "sp=rl&s...")


df = (spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles")
      .option("cloudFiles.format", "json")      
      .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", chkpt_path)    
      .option("cloudFiles.schemaEvolutionMode","addNewColumns")
      .option("cloudFiles.inferColumnTypes", "true") 
      .option("cloudFiles.connectionString", "BlobEndpoint=https://<storage-account>.blob.core.windows.net;SharedAccessSignature=sp=rl&st...")
      .load(path_to_source_data)
      .select("*", "_metadata"))
```

What could I be doing wrong? Why does it keep looking for the account key when I note to use the "SAS" in line `account.auth.type...`?

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because of invalid spark config with SAS key. Please follow below spark config syntax:

```
spark.conf.set(
    "fs.azure.sas.<container_name>.<storage>.blob.core.windows.net","SAS key")
```

I reproduce Similar manner with text format in my environment, I got this output. Replace spark configuration as per above format.

[image]

Comment: It ended up being line: `.option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", chkpt_path)` , I did not include credentials to access that different storage account...fml

Comment: HI @Sauron, above issue resolved ?

Comment: yes it is resolved